# entity framework 5 datetime is null or empty

Tags: c#, datetime, entity-framework-5

I have a table, which generated to class, lets call it "MyClass" ,which has an DateTime Property. I want to check if an object of this property has value, just similar to [DateTime.HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I was wondering if EF5 has an option of HasValue or I should just check if MyClassInstance.MyDateTimeProp is null .

Thanks

Comment: you can't check if MyClassInstance.MyDateTimeProp is null since it is not of nullable type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your property is [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) (`DateTime?`) then you can check if it has value. You may define your property as Nullable. e.g.

```
public DateTime? DateProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 7):

You should change the type of your property to `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` - then you can use `.HasValue` in your queries and also use `property == null`.

If you use model first EF context, you have to change the column in the database to allow `null` values, if you use code first then you just have to change the type of the proprety - EF will automatically generate a nullable column.